# Why is writer not writing the data into the file?

Tags: java

When I run it goes to this file named niceJob.txt and the file that the data come from is called file2.txt which included

```
niceJob.txt 40
20 1 1 5 7 45 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 77 88 99 23 34 56
```

and when I open niceJob.txt it would show

> X8

I am really confused as to why and how this is happening. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JH1_00668860 {
    public static void printToScreen(String filename) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            scan = new Scanner(fis);
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("printToScreen: can't open: " + filename);
        } finally {
            if (scan != null)
                scan.close();
        }
    }// end of print

    public static void process(String inputFilename) {
        String fileoutputname = null;
        FileInputStream file = null;
        Scanner scan = null;
        FileOutputStream outputFilename = null;
        FileWriter ps = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
            scan = new Scanner(file);
            fileoutputname = scan.next();
            System.out.println(fileoutputname + "      asfasdfasdfasdf");

            outputFilename = new FileOutputStream(fileoutputname);
            ps = new FileWriter(fileoutputname);
            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                if (scan.nextInt() >= 0) {
                    // System.out.println(scan.nextInt() + "asfs");
                    ps.write(scan.nextInt());
                    ps.flush();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("You have ran out of data or you have a bad value");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("A file was created");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("You ran into an exception :" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("You ran into an exception :" + e);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (file != null) {
                    file.close();

                }
                if (outputFilename != null) {
                    outputFilename.close();

                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();

                }
                // FileInputStream st = new FileInputStream(fileoutputname);
                // int contents = st.read();
                // while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                // System.out.print(contents);
                // }
                if (scan != null) {
                    scan.close();
                }


                printToScreen(fileoutputname);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("there was an exception");
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        process("file2.txt");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn about try-with-resources: it will make your code a lot less verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are calling `scan.nextInt()` multiple times (2 times) in an iteration of  `while` loop and using the second call of `scan.nextInt()` in writing to your file `ps.write(scan.nextInt())`; it skips every alternate `integer`
2. You are passing an `integer` to `ps.write()`, instead, pass a `string`

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.*;


   public class Main {
       public static void printToScreen(String filename) {
           Scanner scan = null;
           try {
               FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
               scan = new Scanner(fis);
               while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                   System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
               }
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println("printToScreen: can't open: " + filename);
           } finally {
               if (scan != null)
                   scan.close();
           }
       }// end of print

       public static void process(String inputFilename) {
           String fileoutputname = null;
           FileInputStream file = null;
           Scanner scan = null;
           FileOutputStream outputFilename = null;
           FileWriter ps = null;
           try {
               file = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
               scan = new Scanner(file);
               fileoutputname = scan.next();
               System.out.println(fileoutputname + "      asfasdfasdfasdf");

               outputFilename = new FileOutputStream(fileoutputname);
               ps = new FileWriter(fileoutputname);
               int currentInt = -1;
               while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                   currentInt = scan.nextInt();
                   if (currentInt >= 0) {
                       //System.out.println(currentInt + "asfs");
                       ps.write(String.valueOf(currentInt));
                       ps.flush();

                   } else {
                       System.out.println("You have ran out of data or you have a bad value");
                   }
               }

               System.out.println("A file was created");
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println("You ran into an exception :" + e);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("You ran into an exception :" + e);

           } finally {
               try {
                   if (file != null) {
                       file.close();

                   }
                   if (outputFilename != null) {
                       outputFilename.close();

                   }
                   if (ps != null) {
                       ps.close();

                   }
                   // FileInputStream st = new FileInputStream(fileoutputname);
                   // int contents = st.read();
                   // while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                   // System.out.print(contents);
                   // }
                   if (scan != null) {
                       scan.close();
                   }


                   printToScreen(fileoutputname);

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   System.out.println("there was an exception");
               }

           }

       }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           process("sample.txt");

       }
   }
   ```

Output :

```
niceJob.txt      asfasdfasdfasdf
A file was created
4020115745123456789778899233456
```

Comment: What would be the use of currentInt = -1?

Comment: if you want to use `scan.nextInt()` multiple times like inside an `if condition`, printing it on screen, writing it to a file etc, without calling `scan.nextInt()` multiple times (if you call it multiple times it keeps on moving till the last `int`. ex : initially `scan.nextInt()` returns 5 in case of `5 2 3 7`, if you call `scan.nextInt()` for the 2nd time, it returns 2 , 3rd call returns 3 and 4th call returns 7, the last element), you could store the returned value of `scan.nextInt()` in a variable like `currentInt` and reference it multiple times without worrying about the above scenario.

Comment: -1 is to just initialize that variable to some value. Consider a case where you don't initialize i.e `int currentInt;` and in the very next line, if you want to print `currentInt`, you'll get an error saying `variable might not have been initialized`. Hope this helps.